# Using Mojo::Promise in a stand-alone Perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, promise, queue, future

In a stand-alone Perl script, I need to make concurrent calls to an external Web Service (simulated below in `$number+1`). I thought I'd re-use my Mojo::Promise code, but it didn't work - the `on_done()` code does not execute.

I'm open to using better approaches in Perl (queues?).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojo::IOLoop;
use Mojo::Promise;
use Future::Utils 'fmap_concat';

####### STASH ######
my $result_future; #
####################

my $count = 100;
my @numbers = 1..$count;

if (@numbers) {
    my $result_f = fmap_concat {
        my $number = shift;
        my $p = Mojo::Promise->new;
        Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
            sub {
                #sleep 2;
                return $number+1;
            },
            sub {
                my ($subprocess, $err, @result) = @_;
                return $p->reject($err) if $err;
                $p->resolve(@result);
            });
        return $p->with_roles('Mojo::Promise::Role::Futurify')->futurify;
    } foreach => \@numbers, concurrent => 20;

    $result_f
        ->on_done(
        sub {
            my @values = @_;
            foreach my $response (@values) {
                print STDERR "Response='$response'\n";
            }
        })
        ->on_fail(
        sub {
            my $error = shift;
            print STDERR "# ERROR='$error'\n";
        })
        ->on_ready(
        sub {
            $result_future = undef;
        })
        ;

    # Must keep a reference to Futures until we're done with them.
    $result_future = $result_f;
}
print STDERR "Processing $count numbers\n"
```

Comment: How does your code fail? You never `->await` the future or anything.

Comment: If there is a bit of networking that you do with Mojo anyway and this fits in nicely then so be it; otherwise I don't see what is wrong with simple forking. Basic queueing is implemented with [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) and the code is going to be a fraction of complexity of this, far shorter and simpler.  There is also [Forks::Super](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super), with which you can do far more.

Comment: Thank you @Corion this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using this code in an already running event loop, you need to run the event loop yourself for anything to happen. The easiest way to do this is to wait for your Futures to complete.

```
$result_f->await;
```

There's no need to keep a separate `$result_future` reference in this case, because this statement will block until the Futures are ready. This and the related `->get` (which is just `->await`, return results if successful, throw exception if failed) is the primary mechanism that Futures allow you to run non-blocking code in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, as requested in the OP, there is also [Promise::Me](https://metacpan.org/pod/Promise::Me), a fork-based promise.
With this, you could easily do something like:

```
my $p = Promise::Me->new(sub
{
    # Some code to execute
})->then(sub
{
    my( $resolve, $reject ) = @$_;
    my $res = shift( @_ ); # return value from the code executed above
    # more processing...
    # You can use $resolve->( $some_data ); to resolve or $reject->( $some_exception ); to reject.
})->then(sub
{
    my $more = shift( @_ ); # return value from the previous then
    # more processing...
})->catch(sub
{
    my $exception = shift( @_ ); # error that occured is caught here
})->finally(sub
{
    # final processing
})->then(sub
{
    # A last then may be added after finally
};
```

As a full disclosure, I am the author of `Promise::Me`.